# Xcode 7 : Write UI Tests with a deployment target below iOS 9?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

Is it possible the write UI tests with XCode 7 on a project where the target is below iOS9 ? (in my case iOS8.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's the same than with a ios9 deployment target, with the addition that every test case needs a `@available(iOS 9.0, *)`a the top of the class.

Comment: Does Xcode properly obey the @available(iOS 9.0, *) for you when you run tests with the simulator and an SDK less than 9.0?

Comment: I ask because I'm in a weird place where Xcode sees and runs these tests when the @available makes me think that it shouldn't.